# Creat a new column which depends on the range of values of other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have an example pandas dataframe as :

```
datetime               column1
2021.04.10 01:00:00.    10
2021.04.11 02:00:00     15
2021.04.11 03:00:00.     5
2021.04.11 04:00:00.    20
2021.04.11 05:00:00.    15
2021.04.11 06:00:00.    2
```

I would like to create a new column called position which give 25% if the values of clolumn1 is less than 10, a value of 40% when column1 values is >=10 and <15, and a value of 100% when column1 value is >=15.

The example output is shown below:

```
datetime               column1.  position
2021.04.10 01:00:00.    10.        40%
2021.04.11 02:00:00     15.        100%
2021.04.11 03:00:00.     5.         25%
2021.04.11 04:00:00.    20.         100%
2021.04.11 05:00:00.    15.         100%
2021.04.11 06:00:00.    2.          25%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `apply` may be late but never absent :).

```py
df['position'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda value: '25%' if value < 10 else ('40%' if value < 15 else '100%'))
```

```
print(df)

              datetime  column1 position
0  2021.04.10 01:00:00       10      40%
1  2021.04.11 02:00:00       15     100%
2  2021.04.11 03:00:00        5      25%
3  2021.04.11 04:00:00       20     100%
4  2021.04.11 05:00:00       15     100%
5  2021.04.11 06:00:00        2      25%
```

Comment: Can you explain this part for me ('40%' if value < 15 else '100%')...so that is values between 10 and 15 would be assigned 40% right and not just all the values less than 15?

Comment: @StackUser Yes, values between 10 and 15 would be assigned 40%. Values that less than 10 would be assigned 25%.

Answer (score 4):

#### [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

Here is one approach using `pd.cut` to bin/categorize the values in `column1` into discrete intervals having predefined labels.

```
df['position'] = pd.cut(df['column1'], 
                        bins=[-np.inf, 10, 15, np.inf], 
                        labels=['25%', '40%', '100%'], right=False)
```

---

```
               datetime  column1 position
0  2021.04.10 01:00:00.       10      40%
1  2021.04.11 02:00:00        15     100%
2  2021.04.11 03:00:00.        5      25%
3  2021.04.11 04:00:00.       20     100%
4  2021.04.11 05:00:00.       15     100%
5  2021.04.11 06:00:00.        2      25%
```